# Why isn't a range proof calculated using size?

Tags: hash, zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments

For example a Pedersen commitment for an elliptic curve of maximum $2^{64}$, requires every number between $0 \to 2^{64}$ to be checked. Why do range proofs, in the case of a Pedersen commitment, not just work in the power of 2 instead of the numbers itself?